# Apply windows scroll data loading, separately for seperate tabs of twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page with navtabs. Two of the navtabs have search results, the results will incrementally populate on scrolling. The problem is when one of the tabs is active, scrolling inside that tab would also incrementally populate search results inside the other tab. I need to isolate the behaviur for the active tab only.

Since all the nav tabs are effectively one html page, how can I separately apply windows scrolling data loading to different tabs.

To detect end of scroll, I am using the java script, placed inside the head tag

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
                                if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
// my ajax call to load more data and append it to the event
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem .. try to make a separated scroll for each tab content instead of using window scroll bar.